# Supporting USB to UART device via virtual com , Not able to send clearcomm CDC command microsoft.net

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, virtual

We are trying to support an STM32 composite device via microsoft .net serial port. I am unable to find a method to support sending clearcomm command (04) . The .net serial port support page is listed below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.basestream?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

We are able to send break command(0x23)  by using method public bool BreakState { get; set; }.

Is there a way to check the mapping of methods in microsoft serial port framework vs CDC commands?

Comment: What is the ClearComm command and which computer does it do? If the command is to send byte data, it would be the Write method.

Comment: Write is sending data to the device , but Ioctl type commands are supported for COM port . Clearcomm state clears the error counters associated with the comport .

Answer (score 0):

The `clearcomm` you are talking about is the `ClearCommError` of the Win32 API.
[ClearCommError function (winbase.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-clearcommerror)

It seems that System.IO.Ports.SerialPort has no explicit interface.
Looking at this source, it seems to be called internally when reading the `BytesToRead`/`BytesToWrite` properties and when `EV_RXCHAR or EV_ERR event` occurs.
[internal int BytesToRead](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6072e4d3a7a2a1493f514cdf4be75a3d56580e84/src/libraries/System.IO.Ports/src/System/IO/Ports/SerialStream.Windows.cs#L528)
[internal int BytesToWrite](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6072e4d3a7a2a1493f514cdf4be75a3d56580e84/src/libraries/System.IO.Ports/src/System/IO/Ports/SerialStream.Windows.cs#L543)
[private void CallEvents(int nativeEvents)](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6072e4d3a7a2a1493f514cdf4be75a3d56580e84/src/libraries/System.IO.Ports/src/System/IO/Ports/SerialStream.Windows.cs#L1687)

Please try them.